# need to change file created date based on csv

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Good evening everyone. 
I have been able to change date created attribute of a file using the following command $(Get-Item test1.html).CreationTime=$(Get-Date "11/24/2010 06:00 am")

My problem is that I have 10000 files that need to have this done based on a csv file.
CSV has two columns  file name or  and file created date. CSV and files are in same folder. How can I rename the files based on the corresponding date in column 2

eg.

```
1.pdf  2010/12/12
2.pdf  2011/13/01
3.pdf  1989/12/12

etc
```

Thanks in advance. Perhaps I can use powershell to do this 
I can use excel to create 3rd column to get the following. Copy and paste in powershell window did not work

```
$(Get-Item 1.pdf).CreationTime=$(Get-Date "11/24/2010 06:00 am")
$(Get-Item 2.pdf).CreationTime=$(Get-Date "11/24/2009 06:00 am")
```

but then how do I run this file in powershell.

Answer (score 2):

assuming your csv file has 2 headers : FileName & FileCreationTIme

```
Import-Csv -Path 'pathtoyourcsvfile' | 
    ForEach-Object { (Get-Item $_.filename).CreationTime = (Get-date $_.filecreationTime) }
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use `dir` , `findstr` and the `for` loop

```
dir /T:C *.pdf>tmp.txt & findstr " PM " tmp.txt >files.txt & findstr " AM " tmp.txt >>files.txt & del tmp.txt
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims= " %%A in (files.txt) do (echo %%E               %%A %%B %%C) & if exist files.txt del files.txt
```