# How to modify the date-created attribute for multiple files using .csv data?

Tags: powershell, file, attributes, windows-10-desktop

I am unsure on how to word my problem as it's not something I am familiar with,
but Powershell is probably what I'm need to use.

I saw this: [need to change file created date based on csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347191/need-to-change-file-created-date-based-on-csv) (4 years ago)

and would like to know how I can apply this to my problem.

I have many `.mp4` files in the folder `videos` that have incorrect `date-created` attributes.

I also have a `.csv` file that lists the all the files in `videos` in chronological order (using the respective filenames).

The first file starts at 15 Nov 2019, and each successive video is created 1 day after the prior.

How can powershell help me modify the `date-created` attribute of every file using the rows of the files in the `.csv` file.

**CSV FILE:** *contains the filenames IN CHRONOLOGICAL ORDER*

```
video1
video2
video3
...
```

**videos Folder:**

```
name    date created

video1  dd/mm/yyyy
video2  dd/mm/yyyy
video3  dd/mm/yyyy
...     ...        <---- dates are incorrect
```

**What I would like:**

```
name    date created

video1  15/11/2019
video2  16/11/2019
video3  17/11/2019
...     ...        <---- dates are in chronological order according to .csv file
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Doug Maurer provided an incomplete answer (did not work) so here is the working solution:

```
$csvfile = 'path/to/csvfile.csv'
$startdate = [datetime]::ParseExact('15/11/2019','dd/MM/yyyy',$null) 

Set-Location 'path/to/folder'

Import-Csv $csvfile | ForEach-Object {

    #set creationtime
    (Get-Item $_.filename).CreationTime = $startdate

    #increase date by one day
    $startdate = $startdate.AddDays(1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

A) all your files are in the same folder
OR B) you have the full paths in your CSV

AND C) your csv files header is called *filename*

```bsh
$csvfile = 'Path\to\csvfile.csv'
$startdate = Get-Date 11/15/2019

Set-Location Path\to\videofiles

Import-Csv $csvfile | ForEach-Object {

    #set creationtime
    (Get-Item $_.filename).CreationTime = $startdate

    #increase date by one day
    $startdate = $startdate.AddDays(1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Doug! I won't be using your solution just yet, I still have to get a few more files, but do I first need to remove the WRONG `date-created` attribute first from all the files, before modifying it? Or does your solution take care of that?

Comment: It will change it.

Comment: One last thing, is the search based on file name? (the name of file in csv is the EXACT same as in the folder). **SO:** INDEX 0: will look for `video1` in the folder and update ITS attributes, then INDEX 1: will look for `video2` in folder and update ITS attributes etc.?

Comment: It's not a search. It will reference each file by it's name as listed in the csv. Each filename will be referenced with `$_.filename`