# PowerShell script to set "date created" to specific times according to a csv file

Tags: powershell, file-attributes

I have some thousands of files in a folder that I need to bulk edit their creation time to a specific order.
I have prepared a csv file with all file names and the preferred creation times, like this:

```
filename;filecreationTime;
file1.mp4;10/11/2022 2:50;
file2.mp4;10/11/2022 2:49;
file3.mp4;10/11/2022 2:49;
etc
```

I have used this suggestion to a similar previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36348448/20467894 and created a code like this:

```
Set-Location 'path to files'
Import-Csv -Path 'path to csv file' | 
    ForEach-Object { (Get-Item $_.filename).CreationTime = (Get-date $_.filecreationTime) }
```

The outcome is this error, for each line of the csv:

```
Get-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:2 char:32
+     ForEach-Object { (Get-Item $_.filename).CreationTime = (Get-date  ...
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemComm
   and
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

EDIT: After Theos' comment, it run once in a sample subset of my files but never run again. Now it can indeed read the filenames, but it brings a new error:

```
Get-date$_.filecreationTime : The term 'Get-date$_.filecreationTime' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, functio
n, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
 correct and try again.
At line:2 char:57
+ ... (Get-Item $_.filename).CreationTime = (Get-date$_.filecreationTime) }
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-date$_.filecreationTime:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: That is not a CSV file, it is a table. Please open the CSV file in a plain text editor, and copy and paste a few lines from its content into a code box in your question instead.

Comment: Your csv uses semi-colons as delimiter, not the default comma. Append `-Delimiter ';'` to your Import-Csv cmd

Comment: Actually it worked only once in a subset of files that I use as a test sample. Now it brings another error. See question.

Comment: There are 2 things you need to consider, 1. `Import-Csv -Path 'path to csv file'` should use `-Delimiter ';'` as @Theo pointed out and 2. `filename` column doesn't have the absolute path of the files so you would need to `Set-Location` to the path where those files are so `Get-Item` can find them properly, otherwise, a much better solution would be to include the files Absolute Path to avoid such problems. As for the last error, it's pretty clear, you're missing a space between `Get-Date` and `$_`.

Comment: Yeah, that (the last one) was the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.
As pointed out by Theo, the problem was that in my language and regional formats the delimiter of the csv files is set to ";" instead of ",", as the latter is used as decimal...

So I had to insert an additional argument into the import csv (that was not obvious by the error expression), in order to clarify the non default delimiter:

```
-Delimiter ';'
```

So, the correct code for me was the following:

```
Set-Location 'path to files'
Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Path 'path to csv file' | 
    ForEach-Object { (Get-Item $_.filename).CreationTime = (Get-date $_.filecreationTime) }
```